# How to generate thumbnails from .stl files

Tags: opengl, 3d-modelling, stereoscopy, 3ds

I have been given the task to create an application that will scan a directory containing .stl files and generate jpgs thumnails of the models, no viewer or manipulation required. Is there any solution available or should I create my own?

Comment: FWIW, you should probably write an Explorer extension instead. So you could see the model in the thumbnail. Should be documented on MSDN somehow.

Answer (score 1):

[Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) claims to be able to read `.stl` files, perhaps you could prepare a small wrapper around the API that loads the model, captures the framebuffer and saves an image.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial idea, I have been playing with assimp but if the software I'm looking for exists will be better than reinventing the wheel